# how to use esp8266 with arduino mega2560 without reading garbage

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266

I have connected the arduino mega2560 to esp8266 WiFi and have successfully connected to a WiFi network.

but I have all the time strange garbage reading from the esp8266... why is that?

the code I use is:

```c
void setup() {           
  Serial1.begin(115200); 
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200); 
}

void loop() {
   while(Serial1.available()) Serial.write(Serial1.read());
   while(Serial.available()) Serial1.write(Serial.read());
}
```

and when I open the serial monitor, I have garbage printed all the time. if I use some commands of the esp8266 (like At / AT+RST ...) I see a succesful output. and I have succesfully connected to a WiFi network.

Comment: What do you mean with "strange garbage"? Can you copy your code? What have you tried? What do you expect? Please provide more information.

Comment: have you tried to add a short delay() in the main loop and change the baudrate for example to 9600 for the debug view?

Comment: when I changed to 9600 it has stoped responding at all...
the delay is making some changes! I will try it thanks alot!